# T-SQL send mail with excel attachment

Tags: excel, t-sql, email

I want create a SP with T-SQL,
I've 3 SELECT like this

```
SELECT a, b FROM TableA
SELECT c, d, e FROM TableB GROUP BY c, d 
SELECT sum(f) FROM TableC
```

Then i've 3 query results,
I want to send them by mail with excel attachment 
I've find something to send a attachment but only one and with a files already created, i don't want store it in my HDD, just send it !

```
-- Send the e-mail with the query results in attach
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients="Your email",
@query=@qry,
@subject='Client list',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'result.csv',
@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =32767,
@query_result_no_padding=1
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I forgot : If possible i want the 3 results in the same files with blank line for exemple between each result

Comment: Your second query's syntax is wrong i thnk. You need to Group By e as well.

Comment: @QHarr , Its just an exemple this is not real query

Comment: One possible answer is right here in SO. have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289446/database-email-with-attachementexcel-file-pdf-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see.  Ok, well, I tried a couple things and I couldn't get anything to work.  For instance, this looked promising, but I couldn't get it to run.

[database email with attachement(excel file / pdf file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289446/database-email-with-attachementexcel-file-pdf-file)

Maybe you can use Excel to import the data from SQL Server and then get excel to fire off the email.

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = "Hi there"
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is a simple way to pull data into Excel from SQL Server.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     ' Carl SQL Server Connection
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "Server_Name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "DB_Name" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [Customer]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you can actually figure out a way to do it all using pure SQL, please do post back.  I'm curious to see if it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

Email with SQL Server Express:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@account_name = 'MailTest',
@description = 'Sent Mail using MSDB',
@email_address = 'rsuell@spcapitaliq.com',
@display_name = 'ryan',
@username='cx-devdb',
@password='Clarifiuser123!',
@mailserver_name = 'cfinj-mail.clarifi.local'

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
@profile_name = 'MailTest',
@description = 'Profile used to send mail'

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = 'MailTest',
@account_name = 'MailTest',
@sequence_number = 1

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@profile_name = 'MailTest',
@principal_name = 'public',
@is_default = 1 ;

SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_configuration
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_principalprofile
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount
SELECT *FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount


exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'MailTest', 
@recipients = 'rshuell@spcapitaliq.com', 
@subject = 'Mail Test', 
@body = 'Mail Sent Successfully', 
@body_format = 'text'


USE MASTER
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

/* Enable Database Mail XPs Advanced Options in SQL Server */
SP_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log;
```

Also, check out the link s below for some more info on hos to send emails from SQL Server.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/4761260812-Remove-unsent-database-email-from-SQL-Server.html

http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Troubleshooting-SQL-Server-blocked-access-to-procedure-sp_send_dbmail.html

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not configure my DB for send email, for this its ok i've already SP who use this function, my question is how add results query in a excel file and send it with TSQL